# How to add CCMenu to CCSpriteBatchNode?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Many sprites in my scene, which are part of the big sprite atlas, are added to CCSpriteBatchNode to increase performance. However, some of them are needed in order to make `CCMenu`. `CCSpriteBatchNode` complains that I can only add sprites to it. What workaround I can use to batch also CCMenu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no workaround. Menu items can't be batched.

But you could make a regular sprite behave as a button. Layer detects touch, checks if touch was on "button" sprite, executesutton block or selector.